# FOS\RestBundle, "Unrecognized options" on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I've a problem with **Symfony2** creating **Rest API** and using `FOS\RestBundle`

When I try to generate a database or an entity… Whatever I try to generate, an error occurs.

```
root@symfonyRest:/var/www/Symfony# php5 app/console doctrine:database:create



  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  Unrecognized options "prefer_extension" under "fos_rest.format_listener"
```

The problem seems to be in the `config.yml`

*config.yml*

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
[…]

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }

fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        prefer_extension:       false
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
```

EDIT :

new *config.yml* with `format_listener.rules`

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener:  true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            prefer_extension:     false
```

But I've an error too

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]         
  Invalid type for path "fos_rest.format_listener.rules.prefer_extension". Ex  
  pected array, but got boolean
```

Anybody have a solution to my problem ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the mistake !

The correct configuration it's :

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - prefer_extension: false
```

Don't forget the "`-`"

EDIT: Typo corrected

Comment: I am getting the below error, with the above config.... [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]   
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fost_rest" (in /v  
  ar/www/l/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "fost_rest", fou  
  nd "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog"

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the bundle's [configuration reference](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md):

You have not added the `prefer_extension` under `format_listener.rules` but as a direct child of `format_listener`.

The correct configuration would be:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - prefer_extension: false
```